# Using boost::asio::write() boost::system::error_code never gets set

Tags: c++, boost-asio

When using the boost::asio::write() variation with an error object, the error doesn't get set, but instead an exception is getting thrown. Perhaps I misunderstood, uI thought this version would set the error, and NOT throw an exception:

```
try{

    boost::system::error_code error;

    size_t iBytesWrit = boost::asio::write(
        *a_socket_ptr,boost::asio::buffer(a_response.getdata()),
        boost::asio::transfer_all(),
        error);

        (A)
        if(error)print error...


}
catch(std::exception &e){

    (B)
    log error...
}
```

if I cause an error on write by shutting down the client-side of the socket, an exception is thrown
here ( B happens, not A). boost::system::error_code is not set at all. What stupid thing am I missing?

This is tcp and synchronous.

Comment: What is the `error_code` you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on `write` says it will throw on error. The problem in your code is that you declare the `error` variable *inside* the `try`. In the documentation, it says the error variable is set to indicate what error ocurred. Try to declare the `error` variable outside the `try` block.

**EDIT**

After some comments, that's right. Some `write` overloads don't throw. Then, the problem here could be in the other things in play, for example, the buffers, or the socket pointer. It would be interesting to see what exact exception you're getting.

Comment: I don't think the scoping of the `error_code` is the problem here. There are several overloads to `boost::asio::write` that do not throw on error, it appears the OP is using the [correct one](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/write/overload3.html) to me.

Comment: Don't understand why the scope of error would  amke a difference here. Also, this version does not say it will throw. It says:ec

    Set to indicate what error occurred, if any

Comment: I moved the error var outside the try. Didn't make any difference. Diego Sevilla, if you think error var scope has something to do with it, can you explain why?

Comment: @Sam, you're right. My mistake. @Ty: The scope was just to being able to get the error code after the exception, because I thought `write` was throwing an exception. Then, the exception has to be caused by other things, not the write operation *per se*. What is the exact exception you're getting?

Comment: Diego, the exception is simply 'Transport endpoint is not connected', which is what you'd expect the write to throw when the client disconnects prematurely. The problem is not the exception type, but the fact that there's an exception thrown at all, and that the error is not set.

Comment: OK, the exception was NOT thrown by write(). I had a later call to get the remote IP from the endpoint that was the one throwing this:  Transport endpoint is not connected
Exception Type: N5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_6system12system_errorEEEEE.    So that's the end of that mystery, sort of. Still don't know why the error would not be set on write...write appears to not fail. But thanks for the help!

Comment: @Ty you should answer your own question (and accept it in 2 days) so other users searching for this type of failure will see the answer, rather than digging for a comment.

Comment: @Sam. Will do. Thank you. Any idea why the error would not be set when writing to a socket closed by the client? I'll research this one, but just in case you know...

Comment: @Ty `socket::remote_endpoint` [throws](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/remote_endpoint.html) if you do not provide it an `error_code` parameter, just like `write()` does.

Answer (score 0):

The exception was NOT thrown by write(). Had a later call to get the remote IP from the endpoint (after the client had shutdown/closed the socket) that was the one throwing this: Transport endpoint is not connected `Exception Type: N5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_6system12syst­em_errorEEEEE`. So that's the end of that mystery, sort of. Still don't know why the error would not be set on write...write appears to not fail.